# Jenkins Git plugin "Excluded Regions" field missing

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a GitHub repo and I use Jenkins for my CI builds. I am trying to make Jenkins trigger some of the builds based on changes to specific folders in the repo.

According to various documentation sources Jenkis Git plugin supports that functionality via Excluded/Included regions. The problem is I am unable to find these fields on my build configuration page.

Here is how it looks like - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByEy9aJhONyRV0dXUGpZQzkyTHM/edit?usp=sharing

So, where are these fields?

Answer (score 3):

Under "Additional Behaviors", there's an option in the dropdown box that says "Polling ignores commits in certain paths".  This should get you what you need.